# System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled Message=“The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)”

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, module

I'm looking at code that is new-to-me. I have c++ code in a project called UI, with a number of dependencies, which builds correctly and doesn't return any errors. In the same solution in Visual Studio 2008, I have created a new C# windows forms project and added a reference to the dll generated by the UI project, and added a "using" statement. What I want to do is raise one of the dialogs that are defined in the UI project, so I have code like

```
UIDialog uIDialog = new UIDialog(); 
uIDialog.Show();
```

which builds.

When I run my project in debug, when it gets to the "new" part, I get the exception above - with no information as to what the missing module is.

Is there any way to find out what the missing module is, without digging through the code in the UI project?

(I'm trying to rephrase this question so that it doesn't get closed.  If someone could give the definitive answer of "No, there isn't" I'd find that very helpful.  Thanks also to those who closed the previous version.)

Edit:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
  Message="The specified module could not be found. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"
  Source="ui"
  StackTrace:
   at ui.UIDialog.Startup()
   at ui.UIDialog..ctor() in c:\..\ui\UIDialog.h:line 61
InnerException:
```

That's the problem, there's no useful information anywhere obvious!

It's not a 32/64 bit problem - before getting here, I had the typical "BadImageFormatException", so to get past that I forced everything to be 32bit.

Comment: There should be a stack trace included with that exception message. Posting that would probably get us closer to figuring out where the problem lies. Additionally, just looking at what you've provided, I'm going to go out on a limb and speculate that it's a 32-bit vs 64-bit problem. Any chance that one assembly is compiled for 32-bit and the other for 64-bit/Any CPU? 32-bit code cannot call 64-bit code, and vice versa.

Comment: I agree with @Cody. Sounds like a platform target issue. The exceptions typically carry quite  a bit more information so posting the result of exception.ToString() to your question should help in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I hate to state the obvious, but what does `UIDialog.h` say on line 61?

Comment: Startup() - so I guess the JIT is loading something needed in there, but not telling me what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the MSIL Disassembler on the referenced dll and check the manifest for all the dependencies of the dll. The disassembler is part of the Windows SDK tools.

Or there is always DependencyWalker, though I haven't used it in years.

Comment: Checking manually for all the dependencies is what I was trying to avoid (although it is what I did in the end).  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You can [turn on Fusion logging](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) to see what the loader is doing and find out what's missing.